# JToolbar background image

Tags: java, swing, jtoolbar

I'm using a customized JToolbar using the following code:

```
public class GeneralToolbar extends JToolBar{

  public GeneralToolbar() {
    super();
    setBackground(Color.white);
    setOpaque(true);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(54,54));
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(54,54));
    setMaximumSize(new Dimension(54,54));
    setSize(new Dimension(54,54));
  }

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Dimension size = this.getSize();
    ImageIcon image = DefaultAction.createImageIcon("/com/aaa/resources/tabback");
    g.drawImage(image.getImage(), 0,0, size.width, size.height, this);
  }
}
```

Now the image is seen. But I get a opaque rectangle around my buttons.
I tried to set the button opaque to false but it didn't add any affect.
Thank you for the support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you need to use:

```
button.setBorderPainted( false );
button.setContentAreaFilled( false );
```

Of course when you get rid of the Border, then you don't see the effect of clicking on the button.

If you need more help post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) showing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
public GeneralToolbar() {
    super();
    setBackground(Color.white);
    setOpaque(true);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(54,54));
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(54,54));
    setMaximumSize(new Dimension(54,54));
    setSize(new Dimension(54,54));
}
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
   Dimension size = this.getSize();
   ImageIcon image = DefaultAction.createImageIcon("/com/aaa/resources/tabback");
   g.drawImage(image.getImage(), 0,0, size.width, size.height, this);
 }
```